# What is the power of 'Mimic' while it is in the deck?

Tags: smash-up

Mimic's text:

> Ongoing: This minion's power is equal to the highest power printed on a minion card in play.

What is the power of 'Mimic' while it is in the deck?

I.E. can a G.E.L.F. or Sprout pull it from the deck if Zombie Lord is in play??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ongoing abilities are active only when the minion is in play.

When it is in the deck, the Mimic uses it's listed power of 0.  Any ability that can affect a minion of power 0 in the deck can affect the Mimic

Comment: Indeed. A major strength of the shapeshifters is the ability to "synergise" with any enemy faction. For tricky factions, they copy the abilities and repeat the tricks. For bulky factions they cycle and duplicate minions - against a King Rex, shapeshifters have a number of ways that they could drop two of their own!

Comment: So if a `Mimic` was in hand, it's power is also 0?

Comment: @neverendingqs - are cards in your hand in play?

Comment: @neverendingqs Yes, as Pat says it's not in play. You can chain Mimics on the Homeworld, for example, even if each one comes in at 7 power. Mimics won't be hit by a 5-power Leprechaun since the Mimic power resolves first (Leprechaun specifies this), making it at least 5 power too.